# 403 Forbidden errors when trying to install tlp

Tags: apt, battery

I just installed ubuntu with dual-boot

Everything seemed alright. But then I noticed that the computer battery was draining fast. After a few searches I found a tool called "tlp". But an error happened when I tried to install.

I've tried all the ways on the internet but none have worked

```
root@radjabov-Aspire-A315-55G:/home/radjabov# apt-get install tlp
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  ethtool tlp-rdw
Suggested packages:
  tp-smapi-dkms acpi-call-dkms smartmontools linux-tools-generic | linux-tools
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  ethtool tlp tlp-rdw
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 75,0 kB/209 kB of archives.
After this operation, 852 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Ign:1 http://az.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 tlp all 1.3.1-2
Ign:2 http://az.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 tlp-rdw all 1.3.1-2
Err:1 http://az.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 tlp all 1.3.1-2
  403  Forbidden [IP: 94.20.20.125 80]
Err:2 http://az.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 tlp-rdw all 1.3.1-2
  403  Forbidden [IP: 94.20.20.125 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://az.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/t/tlp/tlp_1.3.1-2_all.deb  403  Forbidden [IP: 94.20.20.125 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://az.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/t/tlp/tlp-rdw_1.3.1-2_all.deb  403  Forbidden [IP: 94.20.20.125 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Comment: Look up how to change mirrors.

Comment: Yeah I changed my download server Azerbaijan(My Country) to USA and it works! Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

First try with

```
apt update --fix-missing
```

then

```
apt update
```